# Ruby on Rails: Simple share button by koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, koala

I want to do a simple facebook share button in Ruby on Rails app using koala gem.

The button should be very simple - like this

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

I would like to click on it and then should be opened new browser window to put post on my wall (or login to facebook).

I'm beginner in koala gem so I don't know how to do this. Until know I add to controller show method

```
# part of object_controller.rb
def
   @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.
end
```

and on the view

```
# part of show.html.erb
<%=graph.put_wall_post("hey, i'm learning koala")%>
```

but it wants the token access and I think that there is a better (simpler) solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Koala gem is a realy powerfull tool. If you want just add a share button use more simplest ways: [a lot info about share buttons](https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=Koala%3A%3AFacebook%20without%20auth&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=share%20button%20facebook%20site:stackoverflow.com).

But if you want to do some specific just write about it, I will try to help you.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I have found to add social links from many sites, including the Facebook share button is using the gem 'social-share-buttom'.

Here is a great little tutorial to start using it immediately in your Rails app.

https://richonrails.com/articles/adding-social-sharing-buttons-to-your-rails-app